Bones in finger rig deform incorrectly
I've rigged a low-poly character and everything works as intended... Except the fingers! No matter how much I change, re-align or unparent and re-parent. One joint will move multiple fingers, or one joint will control a completely different finger.

 

Please share your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the full link into it.

The face normals are inverted on the hands of your model as you can see if you turn on FaceOrientation on the Overlays menu (arrowed). - Red is inverted. Blue is correct.

Go into Edit mode with your model selected, Hit A (all) then Shift-N to recalculate the Normals. Then reparent the armature and everything should work correctly.

Thank you so much, you don't know how long that had me confused. Can I ask how did you even think of that? And how could it have happened? I'm really new to modelling and rigging - really appreciate it

I'm not sure how it could have happened assuming the model was all made as one piece. However, checking face orientation is one of the first things that I do routinely (along with merging vertices by distance) if someone has a problem with rigging.
