weight painting not working right


[3

there is the problem, weights seems right, but when i rotate bones, it dont works right, where is the problem?


First thing to do is check the Face Orientation of your object. See my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/322714/bones-in-finger-rig-deform-incorrectly/322723#322723. If that doesn't work I think we'll need to see your blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Try painting all the mesh red with the default brush

Are you sure that the WP'd vertex group that you are display has a name that matches the nearby bone name?  And that the armature modifier on the mesh is enabled?

should bones and vertex groups have same names?

i added blend file

As james_t noticed in the comments, my bone names and vertex group names are not the same, and that's the problem. All I had to do is compare bones and vertex group names.

That weight painting is most definitely not right. Each bone should only influence the vertices directly around it. You don’t have to assign all the vertices down the arm to the shoulder bone, that hierarchy is handled by bone parenting: Moving the shoulder bone moves the bones down the arm by inheritance, and they move their respective vertex groups.

anyway, i tried right painting too, but there was same result

Considering how off your initial attempt was and that you thought it was correct, I just don't believe you.

Fiine ill try again, but i did it

If you truly have done it correctly this time, you now have a separate problem. Ask it as a new question, or if you are sure they are closely connected, update the existing one with new details.
